# Jar file failing to execute with NullPointerException when it runs fine unpacked

Tags: java, swing, jar

I'm attempting to restructure a legacy application and reduce the steps needed to deploy.
To do this, I'm packaging all the class files, and Resources into a jar file.

I'm using this command to jar everything:

> jar -cfm ../Deploy/JEmu.jar Manifest.txt *.class Resources/

My manifest file looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0  
Created-By: 1.2.2 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)  
Main-Class: JEmu  
Name: JEmu.class
```

The class that is the entry point is JEmu.class, which is packaged in the jar, but when I run the jar I get this error:

```
java -jar JEmu.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at ControlBar.<init>(ControlBar.java:88)
        at JEmu.<clinit>(JEmu.java:85)
Could not find the main class: JEmu. Program will exit.
```

I'm not exactly sure what is causing that.

Line 88 of ControlBar is:

```
stopButton = new JButton( new ImageIcon( classLoader.getResource("Resources/stop.gif")));
```

What am I doing wrong, it all works when it's not packaged into a jar?

Comment: Has your stop.gif been added correctly to the jar?

Comment: What is classLoader ? How it is initialized ?

Comment: If possible, please try to improve the tittle to a more specific one. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, stop.gif is in the Resources folder inside the jar file.
`classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`classLoader.getResource("Resources/stop.gif")` probably cannot find the specified resource. When this happens, it returns `null`, hence the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: This answer is correct, I forgot about case sensitivity in file names.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the VM is not able to find the resource named `"Resources/stop.gif"`. The reason for this is that the stop.gif file is located in the package `"Resources"` as it is in the base of the JAR file.  By default, the getResource method will start with the package of the class from which the classloader was retrieved.  In the case of your code it would be the package in which the Thread class is located.  The end result would be that the VM looks for the image in the location `"/java/lang/Resources/stop.gif"`, which is not where your image is located.

If you are looking for a fixed location, i.e., Resource directory located in base of JAR, then make sure to prefix your URL string with '/' as in:

```
classLoader.getResource("/Resources/stop.gif");
```

Another thing to think about is whether you need to use the ClassLoader from the current Thread.  Typically the ClassLoader used by your application class would be more appropriate.  You can retrieve that by executing something similar to `this.getClass().getResource(...)`.

Comment: That's not true. My application doesn't have a package, and once I corrected the case for the filename, it worked correctly.

Comment: You are correct that the answer was incorrect in the case of the context class loader.  I forget that invoking the `ClassLoader`'s getResource directly performed different search logic than invoking the `Class`'s getResource method.  In the case of calling a `Class`'s getResource method, the answer is correct.  Although in your case of not using a package for your application, it would not matter either way.