# Can't open java application when ran as executable jar

Tags: java, error-handling, try-catch, startup, executable-jar

I had a strange problem today... I'm going to make a simplified example since it "worth a thousands words" :D

```
public class Application() {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            A a = new A(); // this may throw exceptions
                           // (which will cause an ExceptionInInitializerError)
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Oooops!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Since it's a stand-alone application with a Swing GUI, my goal is to give a message to the user in case of any problems (in this case at startup)... the code above *works* in Eclipse IDE but when I export the project as executable jar by double-clicking on it, well, it just won't open.

So I try to execute it in cmd with `java -jar application.jar` and it prints in the shell that there was an `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

Why the error was not caught?
It doesn't work even if I specify `catch (ExceptionInInitializerError e)`.

**EDIT:**
After more indepth debugging, I found out that this problem only happens when two particular exceptions occur and the latter occurs in the catch block of the former.
I corrected the bug by changing the order of some checks that I do on startup.

The problem btw should never happen since it was originated by a volountary mistake of the JDBC driver class name to load in a static block.

Well, at least it made me clearly understand why constructors and static initialization blocks should not throw exceptions: it makes debugging almost impossible in the case in which the class that throws the exception is used by many classes, since it may become very hard to find out when the class is loaded.

Comment: And what's in the stack trace?

Comment: make sure that class `A` in classpath

Comment: Do you have a proper manifest file with main-class? Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348258/jar-file-failing-to-execute-with-nullpointerexception-when-it-runs-fine-unpacked

Comment: 1) Change `} catch (Throwable t) {...` to `} catch (Throwable t) {
t.printStackTrace(); ...` 2) Copy/paste the output as an edit.  -- Note that to match the line numbers to the source, you will need to provide an SSCCE (with imports).  I suspect the problem is that the 'double click launch' is launching a different (earlier) version of the JRE, and all the troubles start from there.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three possible explanations for an `ExceptionInInitializerError` not being caught in your example:

- It could be being thrown by `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Oooops!");`
- It could be thrown before `main` is called.
- It could be thrown on a different stack.

In fact, I think that the 2nd one is the most likely, as [`ExceptionInInitializerError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html) is thrown when some unchecked exception is thrown (and not caught) during the initialization of a class.  That could well be happening before you enter the `try` block.

Comment: I think that this definitely *cannot* happen because I don't declare anything in the class with `main()` method and there's nothing outside the try/catch block. If i run with Eclipse everything it's ok and everything gets caught (in my real code I check for other exceptions too).